# Is there any possibilty to choose a next song on Spotify when the app is minimalized?

Tags: high-sierra, spotify

is there any kind of a shortcut to choose a next song while the app is minimalized? I got the SpotMenu and Karabiner app.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard key fast forward works for me without issue. Thats the alt F9 key.
It skips to the next song.